# Migration from grunt to webpack in angular 1.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, gruntjs, bower

I have an existing application in Angular 1.6.

We are currently using grunt and bower to build the application. Now the requirement came to migrate the existing application to webpack and removing grunt and bower. Anyone can give me the right suggestion, how to approach for the same. I am struggling with entry point, bundle path and the loader I am supposed to put in webpack config. The index.html, which script tags to remove and how to include the bundle file. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: this article might help you - https://medium.com/appifycanada/migrate-to-webpack-from-grunt-bower-legacy-build-system-344526f47873

Comment: you can check this: https://advancedweb.hu/2016/02/02/the-first-steps-from-grunt-to-webpack/